# How do I use the MacPorts version of nano as my default text editor?

Tags: macos, macports, path

I tried installing nano using "port install nano", but using the "nano" command doesn't open the macports version.

```
$ which nano
/opt/local/bin/nano

$ /opt/local/bin/nano --version
GNU nano version 2.2.6 (compiled 13:17:29, Nov 26 2013)
(C) 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007,
2008, 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Email: nano@nano-editor.org Web: http://www.nano-editor.org/
Compiled options: --disable-wrapping-as-root --enable-color --enable-extra --enable-multibuffer --enable-nanorc --enable-utf8

$ nano --version
GNU nano version 2.0.6 (compiled 18:58:13, Aug 24 2013)
Email: nano@nano-editor.org Web: http://www.nano-editor.org/
Compiled options: --disable-nls --enable-color --enable-extra --enable-multibuffer --enable-nanorc --enable-utf8

$ echo $PATH
/Users/zach.alnasser/golang//bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

I want to use the nano in `/opt/local/bin`, but even though that directory is at the beginning of my $PATH, the native nano continues to open. Even if I rename `/usr/bin/nano`, it complains that `/usr/bin/nano` doesn't exist, instead of using the macport version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can either rename or completely remove /usr/bin/nano, then:

```
ln -s /opt/local/bin/nano /usr/bin/nano
```

The above command creates a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) from /usr/bin/nano to /opt/local/bin/nano

Comment: A symbolic link! Of course! Why didn't I think of that :). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please don't modify `/usr/bin`. That's Apple-land, and other stuff must be able to rely on the versions of software installed there. In your case, typing `hash -r` into your shell or opening a new one would probably have made MacPorts' nano the default (the old one was used because of a cache in your shell). The symlink isn't necessary.